# How to read dynamic textbox value by div ID and use this ID in another jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use below script for dynamic textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });

});
function GetDynamicTextBox() {
    return 'Item Code : <select name="iuname" id="iuname" class="required">'+
            <?php foreach($tItem as $row) : ?>
              '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>'+
            <?php endforeach;?>
        '</select>'+

        ' Batch : <input id="buname" name="buname" >'+

        '<td  id="finalResult"></td>'+
        '<br/>'

}
</script>
```

When I'll change Item Code from drop down it have to show alert. But it don't show any alert.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#iuname").keyup(function(){

      alert('TEST');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "When I'll change Item Code from drop down it will show alert" and  "But it don't show any alert" both are contradicting statements

Comment: Identifer in HTML must be unique, Whenever you are clicking `btnAdd` you are generating element with id `iuname` hence HTML becomes invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Event Delegation` for creating dynamic DOM Elements

```
$(document).on('change', '#iuname', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $("#finalResult").text(val);
    //if you want add text means
    // $("#finalResult").text(text);
});
```

Comment: It works nice. But I want to show result instead of alert in id="finalResult" . How can I do this. Can you help me @soosmca.

Comment: When I change #iuname  I get some data. I want to append this data into #finalResult. How can I do this? @soosmca

Comment: @MasudSarker  - I guessed I updated my answer please check if you got it mart it as accept thanks

Comment: Nice you are great. But here is some issue. I don't want to show option value I've some data which I get from database by json. And this data want to append in #finalResult. There is any way where I will show my full script because in comment its too long. @soosmca

Comment: Please see above code now. I rewrite the code. @soosmca

Comment: Do you see above code which I rewrite? Can you answer me about it/

Comment: it is better to attach listener on the immediate parent rather then the whole document like `$('#IDofiunameParent').on('change', '#iuname', function(){..`

Answer (score 0):

Refer [On Event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#iuname").on('change',function(){

      alert('TEST');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Identifer in HTML must be unique**. Whenever `btnAdd` button is clicked, Duplicate element with id `iuname`, `buname` and `finalResult` is generated. This results in HTML becoming invalid. the problem can be solved by using a common class then [Class Selector `$('.className')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used.

*Script*, Here I have added CSS class

```
function GetDynamicTextBox() {
    return 'Item Code : <select name="iuname" class="iuname required">' +
        <?php foreach($tItem as $row) : ?>
    '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>' +
    <?php endforeach;?>
    '</select>' +

    ' Batch : <input class="buname" name="buname" >' +

    '<td  class="finalResult"></td>' +
    '<br/>'

}
```

*Event Binding*

As of now you are using Direct Binding of events, Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Since you are creating elements dynamically, [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) needs to be used using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(parentStaticSelector).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$("#TextBoxContainer").on('change', ".iuname", function(){
    //Your code
});
```